# How to detect if the whole string wasn't parsed with c++

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string to detect if it is a number or if it is a name, etc.
And to do it I'm putting examples like "10 ms": it parses the 10 only, without returning an error.
What I want to do is to get if the whole string can be parsed or not, not only a part of it.

Here is my code:

```
string s = "10 ms";
bool number = true;
try {
   stof(s, nullptr);
} catch (invalid_argument){
   number = false;
}
```

It returns that is a number. And the returned number from `stof` is 10.
I have also tried using catch(...), same problem.

Comment: Use regular expressions and read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [std::stof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), it has 2 arguments, of which one is an output argument.

This can be used the following way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    try
    {
        std::string s = "10 ms";
        bool number = true;
        std::size_t nofProcessedChar = 0;
        auto nr = std::stof(s, &nofProcessedChar);
        std::cout << "found " << nr << " with processed " << nofProcessedChar << std::endl;
        auto allCharsProcessed = nofProcessedChar == s.size();
        std::cout << "all processed: " << allCharsProcessed << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument &)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid argument " << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range &)
    {
        std::cout << "Out of range" << std::endl;        
    }
}
```

[Code at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/L7xU4q)

As you can see in the output

```
found 10 with processed 2
all processed: 0
```

It prints 0 for all processed, which is the numeric casting value of bool.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I didn't remember about that part.

Comment: Maybe you want to keep also the try catch if you give to the function something that cannot, in any way, be parsed, it will throw.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Done, I've also added the other exception that can be thrown

Comment: Thanks for your time! You have the tick now, before it woudln't let me set it.